# Retorno indevido a página de login durante a permanência da sessão no sistema

Tags: php

Quando eu faço login para a página `inicio.php` está com a sessão criada.

Quando eu forço o retorno para o endereço da página `login.php` possui um erro, **ao invés de ficar na página `inicio.php` pois o usuário já está logado no sistema ela vai para a página `login.php` que obriga o usuário e inserir os dados de login**.

Pois eu queria que **permanecesse na página `inicio.php` e não retornasse para a página `login.php`** para evitar que o usuário insira seus dados de login novamente.

- `login.php` (página inicial, vai para o arquivo `valida_login` e depois vai para `inicio.php`)

```
<?php
    
    require(__DIR__ . '/conexao/conexao.php'); // Importa o arquivo conexao.php

    // Se existir o id da sessão ou se a sessão já aberta
    if (session_id() || isset($_SESSION)) {
        header('Location: inicio.php');
    }

    // Se existir a $_SESSION['id_usuario'] irá impedir que o login seja burlado
    if (isset($_SESSION['id_usuario'])) {
        header('Location: inicio.php');
    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Login </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/WEB/css/css.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/WEB/js/senha_login/senha_login.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Bem vindo ao sistema </h1>
    <form method="POST" action="valida_login.php">
        <p> Email: <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Digite seu email" title="Campo para digitar o email de login do usuário" size=30 required maxlength="50"> </p>
        <p> Senha:
            <input type="password" id="senha" name="senha" placeholder="Digite a sua senha" title="Campo para digitar a senha de login do usuário"size="30" maxlength="32" required="" onclick="mostrarSenha()">
            <i class="fa fa-eye" id="text" aria-hidden="true" title="Ocultar senha"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-eye-slash" id="pass" aria-hidden="true" title="Mostrar senha"></i>
        </p>
        <button name="Entrar" title="Botão para entrar no sistema">Entrar</button>
        <a href="recuperar_senha.php" title="Recuperar sua senha de login através de seu email">Esqueceu sua senha?</a>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

- `inicio.php` (se o login for feito com sucesso fica nessa página, `logout.php` redireciona para `login.php`)

```
<?php

    require(__DIR__ . '/conexao/conexao.php');

    // Se não existir o id da sessão ou se a sessão não estiver aberta
    if (!session_id() || !isset($_SESSION)) {
        session_start();
    }

    // Se não existir a $_SESSION['id_usuario'] irá impedir que o login seja burlado
    if (!isset($_SESSION['id_usuario'])) {
        header('Location: login.php');
        die;
    }

    echo "Seja bem vindo ao sistema!";
?>

<p> <a href="logout.php" name="Sair" title="Sair do sistema">Sair</a> </p>
```

Comment: Você tá dando session_start() no login? Tenta deixar só if(!$_SESSION['id_usuario'']) pq talvez o erro seja pq tem sempre uma sessão mas não necessariamente um id_usuario nela, e ai fica nesse loop

Comment: @andre_luiss ainda não entendi bem.

Comment: eu quis dizer é talvez você possa ter uma sessão existente no navegador, e ela não necessariamente ter uma chave com "id_usuario" mas vai cair no seu if

Answer (score 0):

o `session_start()` necessariamente tem que ser definido antes, do código, este if colocado:

```
// Se não existir o id da sessão ou se a sessão não estiver aberta
if (!session_id() || !isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}
```

só executa se a sessão NÃO TIVER UM ID, e se o array de sessão não tiver setado, pode eliminar o if deixando só a instrução de session_start() e lembre-se que todos os requests (seja para qualquer página interna, ou login ou validação) a session deve estar iniciada. Ou seja, em todos os arquivos, que possam se abertos diretamente pelo usuário, indiferente de estar feito ou não o login, a session tem que já ter sido aberta, ou criada se for um novo usuário.

O que você filtra, é justamente o conteúdo, se na sessão, tiver um id_usuario definido, ou válido, e com acesso liberado ao seu conteúdo, então você mostra o conteúdo, se não tem, você pode destruir todos os dados de sessão (limpando-a) e direcionando o usuário para uma tela de login. Nessa validação, é que você pode verificar um tempo de sessão, ou uma permissão ou qualquer outro dado específico que você queira, e se algum não passar, então, você direciona o usuário ao destino correto.

Comment: Dentro do php só deve existir esse if, nada mais a não ser esse if? nem mesmo o arquivo que faz a importação do banco?

Comment: Mesmo eu deixando apenas o if ainda assim volta para a página de login precisando inserir os dados de login novamente.